# Percorrendo array de objetos

Tags: php, array, foreach, objetos

Boa noite.

Tenho um array de um objeto e gostaria de pegar dois valores:

```
object(OrgaosJurisdicionais)[17]
  protected 'data' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'nome' => string 'Tribunal de Justiça do Estado do Pernambuco' (length=44)
      'sigla' => string 'TJPE' (length=4)
  protected 'vdata' => null
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'nome' (length=4)
      1 => string 'sigla' (length=5)
```

Como faço para pegar apenas o ID e o NOME desse array?

Usei o foreach abaixo mais não retornou valor algum:

```
foreach ($unidades as $keys => $unidade)
        {
            echo $keys.' - '.$unidade->nome;
        }
```

Comment: Você precisa dos dados em `data`, que é um campo `protected`. Você possui algum método público na classe `OrgaosJurisdicionais` que te permite acessar esse valor?

Answer (score 7):

Acredito que sua variável `unidades` é um array de objetos **OrgaosJurisdicionais**, esse objeto possui um atributo chamado data e é uma array que contém os dados `id` e `nome`, então pra pegar o valor id por exemplo, tem que acessar o atributo data e posteriormente a chave id.

```
<?php
foreach ($unidades as $keys => $unidade) {
    echo $unidade->data['id'] . ' - ' . $unidade->data['nome'];
}
```

Comment: Único problema é que `data` é um campo `protected` do objeto e você não conseguirá acessá-lo assim.

Answer (score 2):

Você consegue extrair todos os valores com `array_map`

```
$valores[] = array_map(function($obj) {
    return array($obj->data['id'], $obj->data['name']);
}, $unidades);
```

Comment: Único problema é que `data` é um campo `protected` do objeto e você não conseguirá acessá-lo assim.

Comment: Sim, acho que precisará chamar um método que retorne isso ao invés de acessar diretamente o atributo `protected`.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver simplesmente com:

```
echo $unidade->id.' - '.$unidade->nome.'<br>';
```

em vez de

```
echo $keys.' - '.$unidade->nome;
```

ficando assim:

```
foreach ($unidades as $keys=>$unidade)
{
    echo $unidade->id.' - '.$unidade->nome.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Esse é exatamente o mesmo código que você colocou na pergunta e que disse não ter funcionado. Por que agora funcionou?

Comment: Você tem razão, Anderson. Olhando aqui verifiquei que realmente usei a mesma função, mas com num parâmetro de critério diferente. O problema estava justamente nos campos `protected`, como você falou, pois esse parâmetro não tem esses campos protegidos.
Valeu amigo.

Comment: Então acho que tanto a pergunta quanto a resposta carecem de mais detalhes. Parece-me que o problema real foi omitido em ambas.